# There is a way to transform string to unicode string in python?

Tags: python, string, unicode

in python i need to transform particular string where some character need to be transformed in unicode sintax. For example:

"Città"->"Citt\u00E0"

I need a string in the second form in order to print it on a file.

I've tried some function but the problem i have now is that the string must be transform in the following way

"Citt\xe0"->"Citt\u00E0"

there is a way to perform this transformationa and the reverse operation?

Comment: This is not a meaningful question. `"Città"` and `"Citt\u00E0"` **are the same thing**. If you want a string that actually contains a backslash and a lowercase u etc., then that is `"Citt\\u00E0"`.

Comment: The two string are different. What i want is that the charactera 'à' must be converted in the string '\u00E0'.

Comment: What is the encoding of the source string? UTF8?

Comment: No, they are not different. If you type `'\u00E0'` at the interpreter prompt, it will report back `'à'` to you. Because they are the same.

Comment: Seems like an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Are you doing this to generate a JSON response?  If so use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand that you want to print \u00EO in  a file literally.
Here is a sample program that, looks if ord of character is >127, and if so converts it to the format you wanted.
In this example sample.txt will have output as. Hope this heps
Cittàá
Citt\u00E0\u00E1

```
with   open("sample.txt","w") as fd:
    my_var='Citt\xe0\xe1'
    final_str = [my_var[idx] if ord(my_var[idx]) <= 127 else "\\u00"+str(hex(ord(my_var[idx]))).replace("0x","").capitalize()  for idx in range(len(my_var))]
    val="".join(final_str)
    fd.write(my_var+"\n")
    fd.write(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following (partially commented) script could help:

```
import re

x = "\\x66  € Città di …";
#    ↑↑↑↑↑ │  │     │  └─ ASCII               Unicode Range U+0000..U+007F   
#          │  │     └──── Latin-1 above ASCII               U+0080..U+00FF
#          │  └────────── BMP     above Latin-1             U+0100..U+FFFF
#          └───────────── Unicode above BMP                 U+10000..U+10FFFD
y = x.encode('unicode_escape').decode();
#           ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓                         negative lookbehind assertion
z = re.sub('(?<!\\\\)\\\\x(?=[0-9A-Za-z]{2})', '\\\\u00', y);
#                         ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑  positive lookahead assertion
a = ( z.encode('raw_unicode_escape').
        decode('unicode_escape').
        encode('utf-16_BE','surrogatepass').
        decode('utf-16_BE')
    );                                       ### reverse back to original string
print( x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z + "\n" + a ); ### make public every stage
```

**Output** (*Python 3.8.6* on *Windows 10 64 bit*): `.\SO\70046868.py`

```
\x66  € Città di …
\\x66 \U0001f60a \u20ac Citt\xe0 di \u2026
\\x66 \U0001f60a \u20ac Citt\u00e0 di \u2026
\x66  € Città di …
```

**Resources**:

- [`codecs` — Codec registry and base classes](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes)
- [`re` — Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html)